# InvalidTypesException for Generic Pattern Transformation in Apache Flink

Tags: java, generics, streaming, apache-flink

I have problem regarding Apache Flink. I want to have an abstract class that consumes a stream. However the pattern applied to this stream should be interchangeable.

```
public abstract class AbstractVisitConsumer<TEventType>
```

TEventType marks the type of the event that is generated from the pattern. Every pattern must implement an interface called IEventPattern

```
public interface IEventPattern<TStreamInput, TMatchedEvent> extends Serializable {
 
TMatchedEvent create(Map<String, List<TStreamInput>> pattern);

Pattern<TStreamInput, ?> getEventPattern();
```

The abstract  class has a method called applyPatternSelectToStream()

```
 DataStream<TEventType> applyPatternSelectToStream(DataStream<VisitEvent> stream, IEventPattern<VisitEvent, TEventType> pattern) {
    DataStream<TEventType> patternStream = CEP.pattern(stream, pattern.getEventPattern()).select(new PatternSelectFunction<VisitEvent, TEventType>() {
        @Override
        public TEventType select(Map<String, List<VisitEvent>> map) throws Exception {
            return pattern.create(map);
        }
    }).returns(this.typeInformation);
    return patternStream;
}
```

The flink compiler always gives me the error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: Type of TypeVariable 'TEventType' in 'class com.felix.AbstractVisitConsumer' could not be determined. This is most likely a type erasure problem. The type extraction currently supports types with generic variables only in cases where all variables in the return type can be deduced from the input type(s)
```

My class WorkPlaceConsumer extends the aforementioned abstract class to specify the desired event that is generated from the stream.

```
public class WorkPlaceConsumer extends AbstractVisitConsumer<WorkPlaceEvent> {


public WorkPlaceConsumer(TypeInformation typeInfo) {
    super(TypeInformation.of(WorkPlaceEvent.class));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    WorkPlaceConsumer consumer = new WorkPlaceConsumer();
    DataStream<VisitEvent> visitStream = consumer.getVisitStream(env);
    DataStream<WorkPlaceEvent> workPlaceStream = consumer.applyPatternSelectToStream(visitStream, new WorkPlacePattern());

    visitStream.print();
    workPlaceStream
            .keyBy((KeySelector<WorkPlaceEvent, Integer>) event -> event.getUserId())
            .filter(new NewWorkPlaceEventFilter())
            .print();

    try {
        env.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I already tried to implement the ResultTypeQueryable interface and tried to store the type information in the abstract class by passing the type information from the child class at runtime. I also was using .returns for the method to provide manual type information. Maybe I am just doing it wrong. Had anybody similar issues with generic transformations on streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right I had a second look at your problem and you were right it has nothing to do with the lambda expression. The problem is that type erasure was applied to the `PatternSelectFunction`.

You can manually provide the return type by implementing `ResultTypeQueryable` interface. You can do it e.g. like that:

```
public interface InnerPatternSelectFunction<T> extends PatternSelectFunction<String, T>, ResultTypeQueryable<T>{};

public DataStream<T> applyPatternSelectToStream(DataStream<String> stream, IEventPattern<String, T> pattern) {
    TypeInformation<T> producedType = this.typeInformation;
    return CEP.pattern(stream, pattern.getEventPattern()).select(new InnerPatternSelectFunction<T>() {
        @Override
        public TypeInformation<T> getProducedType() {
            return producedType;
        }

        @Override
        public T select(Map<String, List<String>> map) throws Exception {
            return pattern.create(map);
        }
    });
}
```

Of course it is just a proposal and I think you can improve the code ;). But you get the general idea of implementing `ResultTypeQueryable` interface.

Comment: No that always works as long as you do not use generics in the `keyBy` operator. The problem occurs in the abstract class. But thanks for the advice!

Comment: I checked and I am already using the tycho compiler. Any good practices to provide manual type information in flink?

Comment: I updated the answer, with new solution. You were right it had nothing to do with the lambda.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This fixed my problem.